# Wordpressのhtaccessでリダイレクトループが発生する

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Wordpressで構築しているサイトで、スマートフォンでアクセスした際にurlの最後に「?amp」をつけてリダイレクトさせたいのですが、スマートフォンでアクセスした際、ループが起こってしまっている状況です。
こちらどこが問題かご教授いただけないでしょうか？

コードは以下になります。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?amp
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android|Windows\ Phone)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\?amp [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?amp [R=301,L] 　じゃないかな

Answer (score 3):

クエリストリング「amp」は `%{REQUEST_URI}` ではなく、`%{QUERY_STRING}` にセットされています。